# onMissingTranslation event in Yii doesn't work properly

Tags: php, internationalization, event-handling, yii

well i have a configuration like this in the `components` part of my config file

```
'components'=>array(

        'messages' => array(
            'onMissingTranslation' => array('MissingTranslation','handler'),
        ),
);
```

now this is my `MissingTranslation` class

```
class MissingTranslation extends CApplicationComponent{

    public function handler($event){
        $msg= $event->message;

    }

}
```

now I tested it by using `Yii:t("hello");` where in the "hello" doesn't have any translation at all. and this creates an error

> call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   non-static method MissingTranslation::handler() should not be
>   called statically

I remove the `onMissingTranslation` event handler and it works fine so I'm suspecting that the event handler has the problem.

Is this a bug already of Yii? or I did something bad again?

**UPDATE**

this is the answer from Yii

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/902#issuecomment-6732258

I hope this will help to someone will encounter the same issue

Comment: change the function to `static`, instead of `public`, i think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are extending a `class` and to use a class without creating an `Instance` or `Object` you need to mark it as static so that its properties and methods become visible.

Comment: thank you, =), well i already got the same answer in the github repo of yii